# Catch every request and redirect to page with agreement if necessary?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

**Hi,**

I got a ASP.NET MVC website where end users can create account. I do however need them to grant a agreement first time thay login and if not, then thay should not be able to get to any other webpage on this site while thay are logedin.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: What does this have to do with caching and redirects?

Comment: Then make the agreement part of create account page.  If necessary make them click a button saying the have read the agreement before you even let them enter any account information.

Comment: @usr : Sorry, changed the title.

Comment: @Blam : The account my be autocreated while doing things on the webpage and next time thay try to login thay should have to grant the agreement if not already done.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't make them confirm the agreement as they create an account and are waiting until they first sign in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be creating a custom authorize attribute. The below authorize attribute checks if the user is authenticated and authorized and if yes the you have make db call to know if the user is confirmed and return false if not setting a private variable `isNotConfirmed` to true.

In the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` you have to check why the auth. failed and if it i due to not confirmed then you can redirect the user to a confirm page.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
    bool isNotConfirmed = false;

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {      
      if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
      {
        //if the user is not confirmed set isNotConfirmed true and return false;
        isNotConfirmed = true;

        // else return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
      if (isNotConfirmed)
      {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Confirm");
      }
      else
      {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do that is to use the ASP.Net Membership and Profile providers.

The [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) provides out of the box infrastructure to manage users (passwords, password resets, and so forth).

The [Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx) allows you to [store things about your users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx), including a flag whether they have signed the membership agreement.

When a user logs in, check the Profile Provider to see if they have signed the membership agreement.  If they have not, redirect them to the appropriate page.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, you can do the following:

Edit the Login controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
....
if (!userHasSignedTheAgreement)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Account", "ViewToAcceptAgreement");
}
else if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
....
```

When they sign the agreement, assign them to an additional Role, say ConfirmedUser

Then, in controllers that have restricted access, add this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ConfirmedUser")]
```

That attribute will enforce that users must be in the ConfirmedUser role to use the controller.

Comment: Yes, this is what Im already do, what I need to know is how to intercept every request and force the user to sign or logout?

Comment: Updated based on your comment.